# What is the exact calculation that leads to the phasor form term $-j\omega \int_S \bar{B} \cdot d\bar{s}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I am currently studying the textbook *Microwave Engineering*, fourth edition, by David Pozar. Section **Fields at a General Material Interface** of chapter **1.3 FIELDS IN MEDIA AND BOUNDARY CONDITIONS** says the following:

> For the tangential components of the electric field we use the phasor form of (1.6),
> $$\oint_C \bar{E} \cdot d\bar{l} = -j\omega \int_S \bar{B} \cdot d\bar{s} - \int_S \bar{M} \cdot d \bar{s}, \tag{1.33}$$
> in connection with the closed contour $C$ shown in Figure 1.7.
> [image]

(1.6) is given as follows:

> Applying Stokes' theorem (B.16) to (1.1a) gives
> $$\oint_C \bar{\mathcal{E}} \cdot d\bar{l} = - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}} \int_S \bar{\mathcal{B}} \cdot d \bar{s} - \int_S \bar{\mathcal{M}} \cdot d \bar{s}, \tag{1.6}$$
> which, without the $\bar{\mathcal{M}}$ term, is the usual form of *Faraday's law* and forms the basis for *Kirchhoff's voltage law*.

What is the exact calculation that leads to the phasor form term $-j\omega \int_S \bar{B} \cdot d\bar{s}$ from $- \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}} \int_S \bar{\mathcal{B}} \cdot d \bar{s}$? My understanding is that this has something to do with factoring out the harmonic time dependence $\bar{\mathcal{B}}=\Re{[e^{j\omega t} \bar{B}]}$, but this idea isn't clear to me.

Comment: (1) $\bar B$ is time independent; (2) $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} e^{\mathfrak j\omega t} = \mathfrak j \omega e^{\mathfrak j\omega t}$; (3) the operator $\Re$ is linear. (As a general comment, I think you should beef up your knowledge of calculus and vector calculus before jumping into Pozar.)

Comment: @hyportnex Ok, thanks for the clarification.